# Social buttons and changing attributes using EmberJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I'm trying to have two social buttons (facebook & twitter) on my website using EmberJS. I'm binding the URL of those buttons to an attribute `url` (for example).

The problem is that **the attribute `url` is changing, and the buttons are not reloading**.

I did a spin-off of this article on the EmberJS: http://emberjs.com/guides/cookbook/helpers_and_components/creating_reusable_social_share_buttons/

Updated to the last EmberJS version (1.3.1), and added a "change text" button. Try changing the text for the text button, and you'll see that the button is not reloading.

Link to the jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/izOtIYi/1/edit (watch the console too)

I think it's because Twitter is messing with the Metamorph system. How can I bypass this? I'm sure someone faced this before.

The strangest thing is that it's working well with facebook like button.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you load the twitter widget it parses the `<a>` and then replaces it with an `<iframe>`. So even when you update the text property it doesnt reload the button.

One way to work around it would be to rerender the view when the text changes this would cause the iframe to be removed and a new a tag to be added.

I fixed up the jsbin to update the button when the text changes http://emberjs.jsbin.com/izOtIYi/8/edit

I got put the logic which rerenders the button into the component to make it more reusable.

The button will flash whenever the text is changed because its actually removing the existing button and creating a new button each time the text changes.